# SharePoint 2013 add a button to show version history by JS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have added a button to trigger the following JS code to display the versioning history for a list item.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var listItem;
var list;
var title;
var clientContext;
var item1;
var value;
var source;
var weburl;
var currentListGUID;

function getSetListItem()
{
    source=document.URL;
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null)
    {
        weburl=_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
        currentListGUID = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
        if(currentListGUID === "undefined" || currentListGUID === null)
        {
            alert('Please select one row');
        }
        else{
            var webSite = clientContext.get_web();
            var ctx = GetCurrentCtx();
            title =ctx.ListTitle;
            list = webSite.get_lists().getByTitle(title);
            var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(clientContext);
            if(Object.keys(selectedItems).length>1)
            {alert('Please select only one row');}
            else{
                for (var item in selectedItems)
                {
                    item1=selectedItems[item].id;
                }
                listItem = list.getItemById(item1);
                clientContext.load(this.listItem);
                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadSuccess),
                Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadFailed));
                ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }
}

function OnLoadSuccess(sender, args)
{
    value = this.listItem.get_item("FileLeafRef");
}

function ShowDialog()
{
    var options =
    {
        autoSize: true,
        allowMaximize: true,
        title: 'Version History',
        showClose: true,
        url:weburl+'/_layouts/15/Versions.aspx?list=' + currentListGUID + '&ID='+item1+'&Source='+weburl+'/Lists/'+title+'/AllItems.aspx',
    };
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
</script>
```

The code is working well on a SharePoint list page, but what I did is to add the list view webpart to a web part page and then added the button/code. It is strange that the code is working fine when I saved even checked in the page, but it is not working after I published the page. The issue is that, even when I selected an item, when i pushed the button I got the message saying that "Please select one row" as if I didn't select any rows. the following is the message shown in the console.
[image]

Please kindly give me a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes after publishing the sequence of JS files loaded to the page may change. 
In your situation first of all I would catch that exception and look at the stack trace. Most probably it’ll give you the reason.